# Marker and figure size in matplotlib : not sure how it works

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to make a figure that marker's size depend on the size of the figure. That way, using square marker size, no matter what resolution or figure size you choose, all the markers will touch each other, masking the backgroud without overlapping. Here is where I am at:

The marker size is specified in `pt^2`, with `1pt=1/72inch`, the resolution in Pixel Per Inches, and the figure size in pixels (also the proportion that main subplot represent out of the main figure size : 0.8). So, if my graph's limits are `lim_min` and `lim_max`, I should by able to get the corresponding marker size using :

```
marker_size=((fig_size*0.8*72/Resolution)/(lim_max-lim_min))**2
```

because `(fig_size*0.8*72/Resolution)` is the size of the figure in points, and `(lim_max-lim_min)` the number of marker I want to fill a line.

And that should do the trick !... Well it doesn't... At all... The marker are so small they are invisible without a zoom. And I don't get why.

I understand this my not be the best way, and the way you would do it, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work, so I want to understand where I am wrong.

PS : both my main figure and my subplot are squares

Edit :

Okay so I found the reason of the problem, not the solution. The problem in the confusion between `ppi` and `dpi`. Matplotlib set the resolution in `dpi`, which is defined as a unit specific to scanner or printer depending on the model (?!?).

Needless to say I am extremely confused on the actual meaning of the resolution in matplotlib. It simply makes absolutely no sens to me. Please someone help. How do i convert this to a meaningful unit ? It seems that matplotlib website is completely silent on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the figure size in inches and matplotlib uses a resolution of 72 points per inch (`ppi`), then for a given number of markers the width of each marker should be `size_in_inches * points_per_inch / number_of_markers` points (assuming for now that the subplot uses the entire figure)? As I see it, `dpi` is only used to display or save the figure in a size of `size_in_inches * dpi` pixels.

If I understand your goal correctly, the code below should reproduce the required behavior:

```
# Figure settings
fig_size_inch = 3
fig_ppi = 72
margin = 0.12
subplot_fraction = 1 - 2*margin

# Plot settings
lim_max = 10
lim_min = 2
n_markers = lim_max-lim_min

# Centers of each marker
xy = np.arange(lim_min+0.5, lim_max, 1)

# Size of the marker, in points^2
marker_size = (subplot_fraction * fig_size_inch * fig_ppi / n_markers)**2 

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(fig_size_inch, fig_size_inch))
fig.subplots_adjust(margin, margin, 1-margin, 1-margin, 0, 0)

# Create n_markers^2 colors
cc = pl.cm.Paired(np.linspace(0,1,n_markers*n_markers))

# Plot each marker (I could/should have left out the loops...)
for i in range(n_markers):
    for j in range(n_markers):
        ij=i+j*n_markers
        pl.scatter(xy[i], xy[j], s=marker_size, marker='s', color=cc[ij])
pl.xlim(lim_min, lim_max)
pl.ylim(lim_min, lim_max)
```

This is more or less the same as you wrote (in the calculation of `marker_size`), except the division by `Resolution` has been left out.

Result:

[image]

Or when settings `fig_ppi` incorrectly to 60:

[image]