# How does the area of Matplotlib’s circular marker scale with its radius?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How does the area of the circular marker scale with the marker radius in Matplotlib? I would expect it to scale as pi times radius squared, but it does not.

I am trying to create a figure to show a closely packed distribution of N circles. This distribution happens to be regular (it is hexagonal) so it’s easy to know the locations of the centres of each of the circles. I plot these using `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter()`, using the circle marker from `matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/markers.py` for the circles.

Now in order to pack the circles closely, I need to set the area of the circular markers so that they precisely touch each other. I expect this to happen if I set the marker area to `numpy.pi*(L/2)**2` where `L` is the diameter of each circle (in points), which is equal to the distance between two circles if they are to touch precisely. But this [results in a plot in which the circles overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ndpm.png). Here is the code that produces this plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7), dpi=100)
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-105,105)
ax.set_xlim(-105,105)

L = 14.0 # Diameter of a circle in data units 
# marker_radius is L/2 in points.
marker_radius = (ax.transData.transform((0,0))
                 -ax.transData.transform((L/2,0)))[0]
marker_area = np.pi*marker_radius**2
ax.scatter(x, y, color='#7fc97f', edgecolors='None', s=marker_area)

plt.savefig('figure.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Clearly the area of the circular marker in `matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/markers.py` does not scale as pi times radius squared (as it should). Upon trial and error, I found that it actually scales as roughly 2.3 times radius squared. When I set the `marker_area` to `2.3*marker_radius**2`, I get [a closely packed distribution as required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clYhc.png).

I wonder if somebody could comment on why the circular marker size scales in this peculiar way. Also, what is the precise scaling? Is it really 2.3? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code? What is `L`  exactly? Are you using it as the `s` argument to scatter? The `markersize` of [scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) is not the diameter in data units but the area of the markers in points**2.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @thomas. I have now added my code to my post above. `L` is the diameter of each circle in the plot. I understand that the markersize is not the diameter, but the area. The question is why is it not **pi times (diameter/2)^2** as it should be for a circle.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer below, the marker size (option `s` in `scatter()`) is the diameter (in _points_) cubed, not the area of the circle.

Answer (score 3):

I quickly tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640118/marker-and-figure-size-in-matplotlib-not-sure-how-it-works/33674314#33674314) code (changing only the marker from `s` to `o`), and from that it seems that the square root of the marker size equals the diameter (in *points*, see the post I referred to) of the circle:

[image]

From the documentation:

> s : scalar or array_like, shape (n, ), optional, default: 20 size in points^2.