# How to calculate size of marker such that they touch?

Tags: matplotlib, scatter

In the following example code I'd like to choose the size of the markers such that they touch each other. In general that will depend on the spacing of the markers in x and y direction (in this case they are separated by 1) and on the figure size.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

x, y = sp.mgrid[0:5, 0:5]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 80)
plt.show()
```

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33674314/3581217 . It's possible, but you have to take the figure size (inch), margins, etc. into account.

Comment: Also works for circles: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33945420/3581217